# Why the node split when inserting into 2-3-4 tree?

Tags: algorithm, 2-3-4-tree

In the depicted [2-3-4 tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-4_tree) below (from [Data Structures & Algorithm in Java, 2nd ed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672324539)), why does inserting `99` cause the node split of `83/92/104` when it seems like `99` could've been inserted into the right child (the `C` child, into the spot immediately after `97`) without any splitting done?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting 99 into C would be OK in that it would maintain all the invariants, but the algorithm is simpler in general if insert always expands 4-nodes on the way down. Then there will always be room for any needed lifting and rotations. It may help to compare the case where C is already a 4-node itself.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. If `C` were full (e.g., `96/97/98`) and we didn't do the node-splits on the way down, we'd have to split `C` in order to insert `99`. However, splitting `C`  in that case would cause the tree to become unbalanced, which violates the implicit rules of the 2-3-4 tree.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the tree balanced, to guarantee performance. The insertion is recursive and it hits a 4-node (node with 3 values and 4 children) , which will cause a split to be done.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. How is the tree *unbalanced* if `99` were simply inserted into `C` without splitting its parent?

Comment: most of the nodes would fall in the branch starting with the parent.